# Best way to add multiple IP to single interface

Tags: iptables, routing, port-forwarding

My hosting provider routes an IP block to my eth0 interface. Until today I've been adding the block using IP alias via ifconfig, unknown to me that it was an old solution.

I've now learnt that there are at least two other options: [VLANs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLAN), and [MAC VLAns](http://www.pocketnix.org/posts/Linux%20Networking%3A%20MAC%20VLANs%20and%20Virtual%20Ethernets).

I couldnt make MAC VLANs work, but I succeeded in pinging correctly a VLAN. Anyhow it broke my iptables ([check this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/654978/why-port-forwarding-is-not-working-in-this-setup?noredirect=1#comment796546_654978)).

What is the best option and why?

Which solution allows me to use traffic  control on the interface? which allow me to use iptables on the interface instead of filtering by IP destination?

Comment: What do you mean by "broke your iptables"? The same issue as not being able to use interface names or your current configuration stopped working?

Comment: The configuration stopped working. Forwarding by selecting destionation ip didnt work anymore, nor interface forwarding

Comment: I would just use `ip a add 1.2.3.4/32 dev eth0` to add an extra address to the interface. Note that you could even add them to the `lo` interface, linux by default will respond to arp requests on all interfaces.